# Debugging actionscript with existing sources

Tags: flash, debugging

I have existing .swf and its sources. Do I have to rebuild it in order to debug it? or I can connect debugger using existing sources? I use flash builder.

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some debugging-related information is stored in the SWF only when it is specifically built for that, for instance, line numbers are only compiled into SWF compiled with `-debug=true` setting. It is still possible to debug a SWF, given you run it in debug player, but some functionality will be missing. You won't have names of local variables and navigating the code will become difficult, but the stack trace will be there.

Notably, if you have MXML sources, the debugger will not be able to make any use of those, unless the SWF has debugging info. AS sources will help a bit, but don't expect very much. You would be far better off compiling with debugging info.